# Merging multiple apple ID’s

Tags: icloud, apple-id, user-account, accounts, macos

Since getting our first iPad and iPhone and while new to Apple, 3 or 4 iCloud email accounts were setup for at least 2 new Apple ID’s. Is it possible to merge them or should I just delete the least used?They were originally used to manage different users/departments/web pages - etc. I’d like to have 2 ID’s - a personal and one and another for our Not-For-Profit Social Enterprise “Arts4Humanity,” A/K/A “A4H Productions,” “A4HPROS.” Greatly appreciate any light that can be shed on this.

Comment: Apple does not have a native solution to this, and the onus lies on you to do the work yourself. [This page](https://jacksadvice.com/looking-merge-apple-ids-well-heres-way-around/86/) at JacksAdvice appears to have a rather painstaking run-through of the steps you need to take to merge the data manually. I've not followed these steps myself, but they look logical and well elucidated. It was also published in December of 2018, so it is relatively current.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, this is not possible.   It has been requested of apple for more than a decade, and they still do not allow this.   Sorry!